# How many ways can we form an integer-sided scalene triangles with largest side <= N?

Tags: combinatorics

Since triangle is scalene, we can pick 3 numbers [a, b, c] from 1 to N, such that a + b > c, a + c > b and b + c > a.  The result is [A173196](http://oeis.org/A173196) but I can't get a way to obtain the result except by writing a computer program which looks for all possible combination of sides and pick the ones which are valid triangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your OEIS link, a formula is cited.

$$a(n) = \frac{4n^3+6n^2-4n-3+3(-1)^n}{48}$$

And the number you seek is $a(n-1)$, according to the OEIS entry.

So to realign the indexing, the sequence you describe is $$s(n)=a(n-1)=\frac{4n^3-6n^2-4n+3-3(-1)^{n}}{48}$$

---

This formula can be proved using induction (or otherwise---see below). Assuming it is correct for such triangles with sides $\leq n$, how many more such triangles have their largest side of length $n+1$? Summing in a way where the $i$ in the index represents the length of the shortest side, and the summand is the number of possibilities for the middle side, there are

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\lceil n/2\rceil-1}i+\sum_{i=\lceil n/2\rceil}^{n-1}(n-i)$$ such new triangles. The reasoning is that when $i$ is smaller than half of $n+1$, then the middle side has to be at least the complement of $i$, so there are only $i$ options for the middle leg. Once $i$ reaches half of $n+1$, then the number of choices for the middle leg starts to fall, since it has to be larger than the smaller leg (and can be anything in between $i$ and $n+1$). Regarding floors and ceilings, think it through with an even $n$ and then with an odd $n$, and this formulation works.

This quantity is 
$$\begin{align}
&\phantom{=}\sum_{i=1}^{\lceil n/2\rceil-1}i+\sum_{i=\lceil n/2\rceil}^{n-1}(n-i)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{\lceil n/2\rceil-1}i+\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} i\\
&=\frac12\left(\lceil n/2\rceil-1\right)\lceil n/2\rceil+\frac12\lfloor n/2\rfloor\left(\lfloor n/2\rfloor+1\right)\\
&=\frac12\left(\frac{2n+1-(-1)^n}{4}-1\right)\frac{2n+1-(-1)^n}{4}+\frac12\frac{2n-1+(-1)^n}{4}\left(\frac{2n-1+(-1)^n}{4}+1\right)\\
&=\frac1{32}\left[\left(2n-3-(-1)^n\right)\left(2n+1-(-1)^n\right)+\left(2n-1+(-1)^n\right)\left(2n+3+(-1)^n\right)\right]\\
&=\frac1{32}\left[\left(2n-(-1)^n\right)^2-2\left(2n-(-1)^n\right)-3+\left(2n+(-1)^n\right)^2+2\left(2n+(-1)^n\right)-3\right]\\
&=\frac1{32}\left[8n^2+4(-1)^n-4\right]\\
&=\frac1{48}\left[12n^2+6(-1)^n-6\right]\\
\end{align}$$

So the total number of such triangles with largest side $\leq n+1$ is

$$\begin{align}
&\phantom{=}\frac{4n^3-6n^2-4n+3-3(-1)^{n}}{48}+\frac1{48}\left[12n^2+6(-1)^n-6\right]\\
&=\frac{4n^3+6n^2-4n-3+3(-1)^{n}}{48}\\
&=\frac{4(n+1)^3-6(n+1)^2-4(n+1)+3-3(-1)^{n+1}}{48}\\
\end{align}$$

which inductively proves the formula (provided you check the base cases hold true).

---

Induction isn't really needed if you take the marginal summation we started with, and sum over $n$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
s(N)&=\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{\lceil n/2\rceil-1}i+\sum_{i=\lceil n/2\rceil}^{n-1}(n-i)\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\left(\frac1{16}\left[4n^2+2(-1)^n-2\right]\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{16}\left(\frac{4}{6}(N-1)N(2N-1)-1-(-1)^{N}-2(N-1)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{48}\left(2(N-1)N(2N-1)-6N+3-3(-1)^{N}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{48}\left(4N^3-6N^2-4N+3-3(-1)^{N}\right)\\
\end{aligned}$$

---

This counts degenerate triangles with zero area, like with [3,2,1]. In your post, you asked for $a+b>c$ and did not allow $a+b\geq c$ as the OEIS entry does. So to modify the sum to not count such "triangles", you could tweak the summands in $$\sum_{i=1}^{\lceil n/2\rceil-1}i+\sum_{i=\lceil n/2\rceil}^{n-1}(n-i)$$ appropriately.

Comment: The number is $a(n-1)$, not $a(n+1)$. There are $7$ such triangles with largest side $\le 5: (5,4,3), (5,4,2), (5,4,1), (5,3,2), (4,3,2), (4,3,1), (3,2,1)$. Note that degenerate triagles (with zero area) are included in the count.

Comment: Ah, OK. I'll edit.

Comment: I am aware of the formula.  I am interested in how do we get the formula ?

Comment: Oh, then I think I can answer that. I'll edit.